# Binding Issue in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have problem with binding, I'm trying to move rectangle when mouse is moved, this is my list:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="icTables" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ocTablesinSection,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,101,52,0" Grid.Column="1" SelectionMode="Extended" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="705" Height="400" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style
                TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=CLeft,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=CTop,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red" Cursor="Hand" MouseDown="Rectangle_MouseDown" MouseUp="Rectangle_MouseUp" MouseMove="Rectangle_MouseMove" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

In MouseMove event in code behind:

```
        private void Rectangle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDraggingRectangle)
        {
            //
            // Drag-move selected rectangles.
            //
            Point curMouseDownPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            var dragDelta = curMouseDownPoint - origMouseDownPoint;

            origMouseDownPoint = curMouseDownPoint;

            foreach (var item in ocTablesinSection)
            {
                item.CLeft += dragDelta.X;
                item.CTop += dragDelta.Y;
            }
       }
        else if (isLeftMouseDownOnRectangle)
        {
            //
            // The user is left-dragging the rectangle,
            // but don't initiate the drag operation until
            // the mouse cursor has moved more than the threshold value.
            //
            Point curMouseDownPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            var dragDelta = curMouseDownPoint - origMouseDownPoint;
            double dragDistance = Math.Abs(dragDelta.Length);
            if (dragDistance > DragThreshold)
            {
                //
                // When the mouse has been dragged more than the threshold value commence dragging the rectangle.
                //
                isDraggingRectangle = true;
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Every thing works but the UI don't show updated (Rectangle do not move), When I change CLeft and CTop to a public variable and the window as Element-name it works !!

What is the problem in my code the prevent the rectangle from moving with mouse?

// Update --

```
private ObservableCollection<TablesinSection> _ocTablesinSection;
```

public ObservableCollection ocTablesinSection
        {
            get { return _ocTablesinSection; }
            set { 
                _ocTablesinSection = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("ocTablesinSection");
                }
        }

Comment: `When I change CLeft and CTop to a public variable and the window as Element-name it works !!` - What do you mean by this? Post code for `CLeft` and `CTop`.

Comment: @Rohit Vats ocTablesinSection is an Observable Collection of Resturant tables, CLeft and CTop is an fields in each record that describe location of each table, instead of using CLeft and CTop if I had defined a Public variable and bind it to Canvas it works. hope this clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF bindings **doesn't work with fields**. It works only with **`properties`**.

Declare them as properties.

```
public double CLeft { get; set; }
public double CTop { get; set; }
```

Also in case you want to update UI on any property change, you have to implement [**INotifyPropertyChanged**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface on class containing this property.

---

**UPDATE**

Make properties to raise `PropertyChangedEvent`:

```
private double cLeft;
public double CLeft
{
   get
   {
      return cLeft;
   }
   set
   {
      if(cLeft != value)
      {
         cLeft = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("CLeft");
      }
   }
}
```

Do this same for **`CTop`** as well.

Comment: Thanls for your time, But CLeft and CTop each one is a property in TablesinSection class that defined in my project Model, It should work or I'm wrong?

Comment: Under comments section you mentioned those were fields. Anyhow if they are properties, have you raise `PropertyChangedEvent` whenever those values gets set. `TablesinSection` should implement `INPC` like mentioned above.

Comment: Yes I have implemented INPC as:
private ObservableCollection<TablesinSection> _ocTablesinSection;
public ObservableCollection<TablesinSection> ocTablesinSection
        {
            get { return _ocTablesinSection; }
            set { 
                _ocTablesinSection = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("ocTablesinSection");
                }
        }

Comment: Make `CLeft` and `CTop` to follow the same syntax.